# merge two lists python

Tags: python, list

I have two lists:

```
a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]

b = [7,8]
```

I want to merge it into:

```
c = [(1,2,3,7),(4,5,6,8)]
```

I used `zip(a,b)` but the result does not seem correct. Can anyone help?

Comment: Your variable `a` is a list of tuples. [tuple](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#tuple) is an immutable sequence type.

Comment: @beargle That doesn't matter if you don't need the change to be done in-place.

Comment: OK, I was thinking they wanted to append, not replace.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
>>> a = [(1,2,3),(4,5,6)]
>>> b = [7,8]
>>> c = zip(*a)+[b] #c looks like [(1,4),(2,5),(3,6),(7,8)]
>>> print zip(*c) #zip it back together
[(1, 2, 3, 7), (4, 5, 6, 8)]
>>>
```

Comment: This is clever, but I don't find this intuitive. It took a second look. Upvoted never the less.

Comment: I added some comments to help

Comment: meh its pretty readable for me... not as much as the map solutions but about equal to the others and more so than some

Answer (score 6):

`zip()` will just pair up the tuples and the integers. You also need to concatenate the tuple and the new item:

```
c = [aa + (bb,) 
     for aa, bb in zip(a, b)]
```

Comment: ISTM this is the most Pythonic solution (and I hope I'm not just saying that because it's how I would do it).  No cleverness and no map/lambda combinations, it just does it.

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
map ( lambda x: x[0]+(x[1],), zip(a,b))
```

Comment: better and shorter than mine ... may want to provide comments in the code though as you might forget what this is doing later

Answer (score 2):

And yet another version:

```
from itertools import izip
[x+(y,) for x,y in izip(a,b)]
```

Should be efficient and it expresses what you are really doing in a readable way.

Answer (score 2):

And yet another:

```
map(lambda t, e: t + (e,), a, b)
```

No need to zip and unpack; `map` can take both lists at once.

Comment: this is my favorite answer... I didnt know (didnt ever really think about it) you could pass more than 1 list to map... now I do

Comment: @JoranBeasley, This will not work if the `len(a) != len(b)`. `map` fills the excess with `None` and it'll blow up.

Comment: @st0le Thanks for pointing this out! But won't an exception be better than silently dropping elements using `zip`?

Answer (score 1):

```
print((a[0]+(b[0],),a[1]+(b[1],)))
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems clear to me:

```
[x + (b[i],) for i,x in enumerate(a)]
```