# Merging multiple lists in 1 list

Tags: python, list

This what I have:

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['g', 'h', 'i']
```

This is what I want:

```
list4 = [['a', 'b', 'c'],['d', 'e', 'f'],['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

How to fix this?

Comment: You mean `list4 = [list1, list2, list3]` ?

Comment: @khelwood That seems like it, but I need to do it for allot of lists and i need to do it in a loop. How to fix that?

Comment: You'll have to give details of your actual scenario, in particular how come you have a bunch of lists in separate numbered variables to begin with.

Comment: list4=[list1, list2, list3] will work

Comment: People who closed this as a dupe: this does not remotely seem to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710476/merge-two-lists-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only simple put the lists to another list: `list4 = [list1, list2, list3]`. The result will be a 2D list (as you expected).

**Complete code:**

```
list1 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
list2 = ['d', 'e', 'f']
list3 = ['g', 'h', 'i']

list4 = [list1, list2, list3]

print("Result: {}".format(list4))
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
Result: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f'], ['g', 'h', 'i']]
```

Answer (score 3):

To create a list of lists like this simply use:

```
list4 = [list1, list2, list3]
```

Answer (score 1):

```
res = []
for l in (lis1, list2, list3):
    res.extend(l)
```

That would give you yet another list, named `res` that is "flattered" representation of those three sublists.

Comment: Your solution doesn't match with the questioner expectation. The questioner wants to get a 2D list. But in your case the lists will be merged and the result will be a 1D list (`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i']`). Furthermore there is a typo in your iterator (`lis1` instead of `list1`).