# Append two individual lists to list of lists

Tags: python, list, nested-lists

Let's say I have:

```
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
```

Now I want to create a list of list from a and b, I would do it like this:

```
c=[a,b]=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

As `a.append(b)` would result in: `[1,2,3,b]=[1,2,3,[4,5,6]]`

Now let's say there exists anew list which I want to append to c:

```
d=[7,8,9]
```

I now have to do `c.append(d)` to get `[[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9]]`

Because

```
e=[c,d]=[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[7,8,9]]
```

How can I get a list of list from individual lists without know how my lists are structured?

Comment: If you want everything to end up in a 1D list, you could just use a.extend(b).

Comment: I think you need to know how they are structured. In the first instance there is no outer list containing all the others (i.e. `c`). You need to create that before you can begin appending other lists to it. Perhaps you could just begin with `c = []` and append all the list to it that you want?

Comment: @Paul Rooney this should work, you can post this as a separate answer if you want, then I would mark it as the solution

Comment: Does this answer your question? [merge two lists python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710476/merge-two-lists-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two actions you are describing are distinctly different. The first is creating the outer list (a.k.a. `c`) and the second is appending to it.

To make the process more uniform you can just start off with an outer list and append all the child lists to it.

```
c = []
a=[1,2,3]
b=[4,5,6]
d=[7,8,9]

c.append(a)
c.append(b)
c.append(d)
```

c is now

```
[[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]],[7,8,9]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```python
a = [1,2,3]
b = [4,5,6]
c = []

c.append(a)
c.append(b)
```

This should work, and only takes 2 simple lines.

Comment: but these are ugly loops, there shoud be list expression for this

Comment: if a=[1,2,3] and b=[4,5,6]. c=a+b would give c=[1,2,3,4,5,6] but I want c=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]] same problem for c=[*a,*b]

Comment: @sebko_iic There is no loop and this answer is correct.

Answer (score 1):

A bit roundabout of a way but looks nice, using numpy

```
a = np.array([[1,2,3]])
b = np.array([[4,5,6]])
c = np.append(a,b,axis=0)
print(c.tolist())
```

gives you

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Appending another list in the same way keeps the structure of list of lists, for example

```
d = np.array([[7,8,9]])
e = np.append(c,d,axis=0)
print(e.tolist())

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Now this is quite roundabout. I would just keep everything in numpy arrays if possible.

EDIT: Figured out how to do this without numpy

Simply state each list as a list of lists to begin with

```
a = [[1,2,3]]
b = [[4,5,6]]
a.extend(b)
print(a)

[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

Furthermore you can do this

```
d = [[7,8,9]]
a.extend(d)
print(a)

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Comment: Solution is good, I wish I could use numpy :(